# How to enable a radio button based on combo box item in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have a combo box having 5 items and i have two radio buttons. I want to enable a first radio button if first item selected in combo box unless the second radio button must enabled.
How can I do that in wpf? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share the XAML for the combobox and the two radio buttons, as well as the code that creates the combobox items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the ComboBox SelectionChanged event and then in the back you can do something like this:

```
  private void cmb_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo = sender as ComboBox;
        if (combo.SelectedIndex == 0)
            rad1.IsChecked = true;
        else
            rad2.IsChecked = true;
    }
```

here rad1 and rad2 are your radio buttons defined in the xaml.

Comment: kindly mention the reason for down voting the answer.

Comment: I guess you got downvoted because you are checking the radiobutton, instead of enable/disable it. Your answer doesn't answer completely to the question.

Comment: Its Perfectly working .